# CSS First-child bug? or intended behavior?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following set up

```
.test div:first-child {};

<div class="test" id="one"> 

    <div id="two"> 

        <div id="three"> 
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Somehow div#three inherits the first-child styles, even though it is not the first-child of div.test.  Is this intentional by the browsers?  Can someone explain this?

Comment: i think you've got a typo, 2 divs with the id '3'  also, id's should never start with numbers.

Comment: `.test > div:first-child {}` if you only want it to apply to `div#2`

Comment: yes the ID thing was literally for the purpose of this question so people can identify the divs im talking about

Comment: I fixed the IDs by spelling out the names of the numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While `#two` is the first child of `#one` but `#three` isn't, `#three` is still the first child of `#two`. So both inner `div`s get the styles.

The descendant combinator (the space character) in your selector tells the browser to select any `div` in any level of nesting from `.test`, as long as it's contained somewhere within an element with that class. The `:first-child` pseudo-class says to only select an element if it's the first child of **its parent, whatever that parent may be**, not just the element represented on the left side of the combinator.

If you only want to target the first child of `.test`, use the child combinator `>`:

```
.test > div:first-child {}
```

Because `>` expresses a parent-child relationship, it is safe to imply that the parent concerned by `div:first-child` is represented by `.test`.

Comment: Got it.  I misunderstood first-child.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted. That way other users can more easily see what worked, and people will be more apt to answer any future questions you might have.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me immensely. I was tearing my hear out for an hour or so.

Answer (score 1):

This is the intended behaviour. You need to write your CSS rule like this:

```
.test > div:first-child
```

The `>` ensures only the first child of the `.test` element is selected. Without it, any `div` that is the first child of *any node* within `.test` is selected.